# Java ExecuteBatch() inserts only 1 row

Tags: java, jdbc

My code is very simple. but after running executeBatch() only 1 row gets into the DB.

The code is below:

```
//INSIDE LOOP: 
{
ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO NK_EVENT_DATA VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?);

// setting bind variable values
ps.setLong(1, ed_fi_uid);
ps.setString(2 , ed_date);
ps.setString(3, ed_hash_key);
ps.setLong(4 , ed_et_uid);
ps.setLong(5, ed_etn_uid);

ps.addBatch();
}
//LOOP ENDS

ps.executeBatch();
```

However, only one record gets inserted instead of the 5 records.

Comment: Post your complete code.

Comment: 5 ? You are usinng 5 variables in the prepared statement but not 5 records ...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are creating a new PreparedStatement in each loop.  Each statement only gets one batch added to it, and only the last statement gets executed.

Move `ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO NK_EVENT_DATA VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?);` outside the loop.

Comment: Hi Michael !!! This was the issue exactly !! Now its working Fine !! Cheers Man, THanks a Lot !! Abdullah

Answer (score 0):

How do you know there should be 5 rows inserted?

In order this to happen, there must occur 5 calls to the `addBatch` method, which most likely means that your code has to iterate 5 times through the loop. Please check if this is happening.

Also, please be aware that your `INSERT` statement looks like it expects to insert data into 7 columns, while you're setting only 5 column values for each row.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, and the issue was an ; at the end of my prepared statement string. Just removed ; from the string and it worked.